# how do I programically create a page in WordPress if it doesn’t exist already?

Tags: php, wordpress

how do I programically create a page in WordPress if it doesn’t exist already?

Comment: you mean, you wish you never have 404 error on your wordpress blog/website ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you want to create a new page, it is the "Page" menu of the WordPress admin panel.
If you want to redirect the user if he tries to access a page that doesn't exist, you have to create a redirection rule in the configuration of your web server (Apache, Nginx, Lighttpd, etc.)

Comment: I want to write a plugin and to put some html controls in a page which will automatically create when user install the plug in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to write a plugin and to put some html controls in a page which will automatically create when user install the plug in

Based on that comment, you want to hook a function to your plugin's activation hook, which inserts a WordPress post object into the database;

```
function my_plugin_activate()
{
    wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => 'Page Title',
        'post_content' => 'Page Content',
        'post_name' => 'page-slug',
    ));
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
```

Answer (score 5):

How will you identify that `page`? Assuming you have a specific title, use something like

```
if( get_page_by_title('my_title') === false ) // page doesn't exist
{
    // insert the page using wp_insert_post
}
```

If you need help with wp_insert_post, please comment.

Comment: Should be:  get_page_by_title('my_title') === NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function that intercepts the [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) action/filter, and inside that function include the theme's header and footer, while creating your own content to put into the body of the page. See the API link (above) for an example.

Here's a [tutorial](http://co-opmedia.org/2010/05/template-redirect/) on the web.